# Unable to open Scilab Console

Tags: 18.04, scilab

Recently I have installed **ubuntu 18.04** on my laptop and I have downloaded all the necessary packages which included ***scilab version 6.0.1***, but I am unable to open neither the **scilab console** nor **scilab advance**. Only my **scilab CLI** seems to open when I click it. Can someone help me out please as I am new to this Ubuntu

Comment: How did you install scilab?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? How *exactly* did you install Scilab and (try) to start its console, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to download scilab yourself, you can simply install it from the repository using the following command:

```
sudo apt install scilab
```

If you use this, it should automatically install all necessary desktop shortcuts so you can start scilab using the normal gnome way (using the *Activities* button for instance)